# Re-initialize library variables in C program

Tags: c, linux, service, shared-libraries

I am trying to write a program where I have to call some functions through a (shared) library (its source is available). The C code for the library has several global variables, and many functions change the values of these global variables. What I have to do in my program requires that each function call that I make gets to work with a fresh set of variables.

For example, let this function be a part of the library:

```
int x = 1;

int foo()  
{  
    int a = 0;
    //do somethings to 'a'
    //...
    x++;
    return a;
}
```

Now every time I invoke `foo()` from my program, the value of `x` gets update from 1 to 2 then 3 then 4 and so on... I am try to construct a program so that every time `foo()` is invoked, it sees x = 1.

I am sorry to say that my knowledge of how C/linux treat these variable spaces is insufficient, so this question may seem vague. The above is just a small example; in reality, there are so many variables that is practically impossible to reset their values manually.

What may be the best way to compile that library and/or use it my program so as to refresh the variables?

(On a side note, what I am also trying to do is to parallelize calls to foo(), but because of the shared variables, I cannot do that.)

EDIT:
When working on some web dev projects, I used to encapsulate some code in webservices and then invoke those services from the main program. Does a similar framework exist in C/Linux? Please note that functions are returning data.

Comment: your side note suggest that what you're asking for won't solve your real problem.

Comment: Thanks! Any suggestions? Can we create something like a service and call it from my program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have discovered one of the main reasons that global variables (or global state in general) are a *really bad idea*.

Since you have access to the source, I would suggest investing some time to refactor the source code.

You can achieve the ability to parallelize calls to *foo* with the following strategy:

- Gather up all of the global variables into a single *struct*.  Call it something like *Context*.
- Change each function that acts on a global variable to take a pointer to a *Context*, and change the function to update the variables in the *Context* instead of updating global variables.
- Now each thread that wants to use the library can create a new *Context* and pass that into *foo* and related functions.

If it's not feasible to make such a change to the source code, you can use more than one CPU core by starting [child processes](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html).  Each child process has it's own memory space.  That option is not nearly as efficient as using multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks. There are hundreds of thousands of lines of code in the library source. I can't even imagine trying to go around changing each variable's usages.

Comment: The only other approach I can think of to do things in parallel is to start multiple child processes.  Certainly not efficient as threads, but possibly a solution.  Updating my answer to include this possibility.

Comment: This definitely helps. Just one more thing: each child process calculates a value, and I am trying to sum all these values in the parent after wait(). But for obvious reasons, I can't retrieve these values (or store them in the parent's memory while the child is executing). Can you suggest something?

Comment: You would need some form of interprocess communication.  That could be as simple as the child process writing a file with it's process ID when done (remember to clear out old files before a new run) or you could use one of the methods listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849147/communicating-between-a-parent-and-its-children

Answer (score 0):

I have no answer in details. But you can try one of the following:

1. unload and load library
2. try to clear library's .bss and fill .data section with values from the library (ref dl_iterate_phdr() call).